# Firefox 57 / block Javascript per site

Tags: javascript, firefox, block

As you all might know, Mozilla is migrating its addon system to WebExtension and so many addons break from version 57+, see more here:

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/

In the past I used "Yes Script" and "No Script" to allow Javascript everywhere and block it on specific sites only. However they are not supported in FF 57 (I'm on beta now) and the developer of "Yes Script" does not plan to upgrade it in the future. But I'd like to block JS on specific sites. Any idea how I might achieve that?

Could I do that modifying prefs.js or user.js? I would prefer to do this without any extension if possible. Thanks.

Comment: This question might be a better fit at [su].

Comment: Didn't realize that. Thanks.

Comment: [umatrix is available in the dev channel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/versions/beta?page=1#version-1.0.1rc3) over on AMO.

Comment: moved it here: https://superuser.com/questions/1254800/firefox-57-block-javascript-per-site

Comment: @Andy umatrix seems overkill for me, though it has nice features - all I'm looking for right now is blocking javascript on specific domains, thx

Comment: @log69 You can use this extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-js-switcher